# Activity is SingleTask and is root in task, reStart activity of top is destroyed?

Tags: android

- A Activity is SingleTask
- B Activity and C Activity is Standard,

  A -> B -> C, Then press Home,  re-press the application icon, Why B,C destroy?  Why B destroyed firstly, C destroyed later?

  ```
  <activity
      android:name=".Main1Activity"
      android:launchMode="singleTask">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.example.dell.taskdemo.Main2Activity" />
  <activity android:name="com.example.dell.taskdemo.Main3Activity" />
  ```

```
public class Main1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println("---1:  onCreate  " + getTaskId());
    }

    public void enter(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        System.out.println("---2:  onCreate  " + getTaskId());
    }

    public void enter(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class));
    }
}

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        System.out.println("---3:  onCreate  " + getTaskId());

    }
}
```

Comment: could you pls add code of starting **A** and **B** activities?

Comment: with out the code being posted, we can only give vague answers...

Comment: Thanks! There are code edited, please explain the result?

Answer (score 1):

in short "singleTask" activity allows other activities to be a part of its task...so when ever you re-open the app again, the Activity a is shown because as of now activity b,c are part of its task...

the activity b is deleted first because, it started before the Activity c.

Comment: @canyifenglin sorry about the late comment...A is shown because A is the entry point of the app because of the line:  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest file and ensure that Activity B and C are not set to "noHistory=true."  If they are, remove that line and it should fix your issue.

Activity B and C should not be destroyed simply because Activity A is SingleTask.  Having a SingleTask activity simply means it has to be at the bottom of the activity stack - so it exists once and only once.  If B and C are finishing each time you close the app, it's because B and C are not set properly.  So the issue is with B and C, not with A.

Comment: My mainfest file not set "noHistory=true", but singleTask activity is not bottom of the stack. You try to print log to look please.